# Azure Java Function based on deviceTwinTrigger: Retrieve DeviceId

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

Following this guide:https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---java-example

I am working on a Java Function, that has to run in Azure. In my IoT-hub I have a route defined, which triggers all device twin changes towards an event hub. From there, my function gets triggered nice and easy, and I can log the content that was indeed changed. So far so good, but..

How can I extract the device id? Right now, I only retrieve the message (content of what has been changed in the device twin) but I have no idea to which device this content change belongs.

Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have met a [known issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-templates/issues/811#issuecomment-443915634) that current implementation of Event Hub binding data missed some properties like the device id you seek.

> In our binding, we absorbed this change by outputting just the 4 top level properties from that type, not realizing that it derives from Dictionary. So the code where we populate binding data [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/584a3f69194dd9a2d3b71947a1e706b59f168915/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/Triggers/EventHubTriggerInputBindingStrategy.cs#L127) is a bug. Rather than our own ToDictionary implementation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/584a3f69194dd9a2d3b71947a1e706b59f168915/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/Extensions/SystemPropertiesCollectionExtensions.cs#L12) for these 4 properties (which filters out other system properties), we should just be adding the entire collection, which is already a dictionary.

And here's the [thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2068) tracking the fix for the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Any idea if there is a work-around we can use for now perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't found any workaround except using v1 function. But v1 doesn't support java at all.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

By now, it has been released :-)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2068

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/releases/tag/v3.0.5

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12353